# How to add a JAR file as an external tool in Visual Studio and/or IntelliJ

Tags: java, visual-studio-2013, intellij-idea, jar

I have built a command line tool for IDE's, but now it seems that you can't add JAR's as external tools. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The best option that I'm familiar with is to convert your JAR file into DLL. this can be achieved by  a converter tool from jar to dll like Jbimp and IKVM to reference jar. (I recommend IKVM.)

Link to IKVM converter: http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/tutorial.html

Code project guide: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594632/IKVM-NET-in-Details

**Note**: *If you use Jbimp, you have to reference not only the converted dll but vjslib.*

I hope that support your question.

Please let me know if that support your issue.

Answer (score -1):

I actually figured out the answer. It is kind of unintuitive, and other websites/answers have not mentioned it.

In IntelliJ / Visual Studio, when adding an external tool, rather than making the 'Command' be:

```
/pathToCommand/myProgram.jar
```

It should be simply:

```
java.exe
```

Then, instead of providing only your arguments in the 'Program Arguments' field:

```
-jar myProgram.jar -myarguments
```

This will, instead of trying to run a jar by itself, rather run the Java program with the name of your jar as an argument to the -jar command.