# Adding .jar Files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: apache, maven, visual-studio-2012, jar

First and foremost, I really appreciate your help. I am trying to build an application by using an external library Apachi Poi. I know I need to add jar files to the project; however, I don't know how I should do that plus I have been searching on the Internet for a solution, but I could not find one even I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189913/how-to-add-a-jar-file-as-an-external-tool-in-visual-studio-and-or-intellij). My OS is Linux and I am running 1.33.1 version of VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE]: I have fixed my problem. What I basically did was to install maven command to my
Linux machine and now I am using mvn command along with pom.xml to add my .jar files to
the project.